# Apollo Server federation resolvers: how to gracefully handle entity not found?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollo-federation, graphql-kotlin

When using GraphQL federated resolvers to resolve an array, and one of the resolved items cannot be found:

- **Observed behaviour**: null data returned for entire query, no error message.
- **Desired behaviour**: the item which cannot be resolved is silently dropped from results array.

### What works

Using Apollo Server federation, we are successfully able to resolve the following query:

```
query {
  products {
    name
    reviews {
      id
      score
    }
  }
}
```

where products comes from the Product subgraph and score is resolved by the Review subgraph.

This works fine when all the review ids passed to the Review subgraph are resolvable.

### Our Problem

Sometimes the Review subgraph deems that a review should not be returned. The business case could be, for example, it was automatically marked as spam and is blocked until a manual check is done.

In this situation, the Review subgraph returns null for this ID. Example query:

```
query {
  _entities(representations: [
    {id: 1, __typename: "Review"},
    {id: 2, __typename: "Review"}
  ]) {
    ...on Review {
      id
      score
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "_entities": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "score": "94"
      },
      null
    ]
  }
}
```

When this happens, we would want the federated results to contain the Product and only review 1, the non-resolveable review id 2 having been dropped from the array. Like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "name": "Phone cover",
      "reviews": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "score": "94"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, Apollo Server returns null for the entire query, with no error message:

```
{
  "data": null
}
```

Is this expected behaviour? Is there any way to gain the result I want, or otherwise control how Apollo reacts when one item in a reference array is not resolved?

Comment: I would recommend filtering null entities from the result in the subgraph component which is processing the query. I understand you want Apollo to handle the results, but the approach handling them in a component you or your team-mates develop is just faster

Comment: @AndreiIvantsov that doesn't work, unfortunately. If a resolver should resolve a list of 3 ids, for example, then it needs to return three items - either resolved items or "null". That makes sense - if you were to get e.g. 2 items back, then I guess you wouldn't know which item to correlate with which ID.